# SQL Server equivalent of Translate (DB2)

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace, translate

I'm looking for a way to remove any record that begins with 3 letters. In my screenshot, I've highlighted the rows I'd like to have filtered out. It can be any combination of letters though, not just these examples.

[image]

I don't want to lose all records that begin with a letter, only if they begin with 3 letters. Records 2 & 13 (beginning with a single letter) are records that should remain.

DB2 (and I think Oracle) has function `Translate` that handles this, but is there a SQL Server alternative?

DB2:

```
TRANSLATE( 
LEFT( LTRIM( hos.hpid ), 3 ),
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 ) <> 'AAA'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIKE` operator:

```
DELETE SomeTable
    WHERE hospid LIKE '[a-z][a-z][a-z]%'
```

If your collation is case-sensitive, you will need to include the capital letters too: `[a-zA-Z]`.